# Laravel QueryException in Connection.php line 651: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel and have an error.
When I try to check my page, I get this error:

`QueryException in Connection.php line 651:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table "scotchbox.likes" doesn't exist (SQL: select "users".*, "users"."name", "projects"."title" from "likes" inner join "users" on "user_id" = "users"."id" inner join "projects" on "project_id" = "projects"."id")`

This is my migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateLikesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('likes', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('project_id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('likes');
    }
}
```

And my function:

```
public function activity()
{
    $likes = DB::table('likes')
        ->join('users', 'user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('projects', 'project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
        ->select('users.*', 'users.name', 'projects.title')
        ->get();

    return view('user.activity', ['likes' => $likes]);
}
```

I already rolled back my migrations, refreshed them,... But it doesn't help...

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run migration in the console. It creates the `likes` table in the db.

```
php artisan migrate
```

If you would like to know about migrations: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations

Comment: Did that already a couple of times. My migrations are up to date (console says: nothing to migrate)

Comment: Please check your db in phpmyadmin. Really created the table? If not, please delete the "likes" row from migrations table and rerun php artisan migrate.

Comment: I had more than one virtualbox running at the same time... That was the problem

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Create a model with the particular table name, open the model in your text editor add this line:

```
protected $table = 'tablename';
```

So it looks like this:

```
class Gallery extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tablename';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the migration:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Did that already a couple of times. My migrations are up to date (console says: nothing to migrate)